# MySql Cluster - Management node wont start

Tags: mysql, centos

Cant start the management node on MySQL Cluster.

I am issuing the ff command.

> ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini --initial 
>   --configdir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/ --ndb-nodeid=1

And I am getting the ff error:

> MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.5.22 ndb-7.2.6 2012-07-05
>   02:45:24 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR -- The hostname this node should have
>   according to theconfiguration does not match a local interface.
>   Attempt to bind '192.168.177.134' failed with error: 99 'Cannot assign
>   requested address'

config.ini

```
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2

[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.186.177.134
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.177.132
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[ndbd]
hostname=192.186.177.133
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.177.131
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config.ini`, sometimes you have `192.168` and sometimes `192.186`.  In particular:

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.186.177.134
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
```

Should be:

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.168.177.134
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
```

The `hostname` will then match that to which `ndb_mgmd` was attempting to bind, as described in the error message.  You should also correct the hostname in the `[ndbd]` section.